# WCF + Jquery/json consume client security

Tags: wcf, json, security

I'm tired of WCF to say the least. I need a way to use Jquery ajax to call WCF methods in a cross domain environment, so it needs to be secure as well.

very hard to find a solution that use jquery can work in cross domain environment. So far i've founded JsonP with WCF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834511.aspx and it works in cross-domain.

now, i'm in need a way to secure my WCF methods that only sites have my permission are able to consume to service.

Windows authentication seems to be not working with JsonP.  please help me out, WCF knowledge is beyond me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler way to secure a WCF Service is using Membership. Here is a walk through on how do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049(v=vs.110).aspx